# Create a row for each row that doesnt match a merge in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, cartesian-product

I have a dataframe:

```
  uses = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1, 2, 3], 'loop_id': [1, 1, 1], 'another_column': ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello']})
  loop_merge = pd.DataFrame({'loop_id': [1, 2], 'description': ['foo', 'bar']})
```

I want to merge like `pd.merge(uses, loop_merge, on='loop_id')` then and after everything I want to have a dataframe like:

| person_id | another_column | loop_id | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 1 | foo |
| 1 | None | 2 | bar |
| 2 | Hi | 1 | foo |
| 2 | None | 2 | bar |
| 3 | Hello | 1 | foo |
| 3 | None | 2 | bar |

So what I really want is to merge both of dataframes and where loop_id doesnt match I want to create a row for that person(with that missing data in another_column). Can anyone help me please?

Comment: That sounds like an outer join. Try with `how="outer"` in your merge command.

Comment: NB: I appreciate the ready-made code for the two dataframes. Just please make sure the code is actually without syntax error (e.g., by copy-pasting it yourself into a Python interpreter prompt or notebook).

Comment: No thats not what I wanted because an outer property will only make all rows from each of the tables go inside this new table. I want to merge what i can merge and what doesnt merge for each person I will create a row for each of them.

Comment: You also have the problem that `loop_id` in `uses` only contains 1's. So it's rather random to get `loop_id`'s of 2 in your output frame when you merge on `loop_id`. I mean, it can't match 2, so how should that part merge?

Comment: why is only "another_column" affected? why not "personal_id" as well?

Comment: Well, thats the problem. I need to create those rows with loop_id = 2 for each row in the other dataframe that doesnt match when I merge in loop_id. Maybe its a merge with some other function of pandas. It is something like an cartesian product

Comment: The thing is that I want for each person to have all loop_id rows and if any of loop_id matches the 'another_column' will be filled, if not 'another_column' will be None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. THe solution for my problem was to create another dataframe with all possibilities for each person, so I had to do a cross merge between only the person_id and the loop_merge dataframe. After that I just had to merge this new dataframe with the uses dataframe with how="left" and on=["person_id", "loop_id"].

```
df_aux = pd.merge(uses[["person_id"]], loop_merge, how="cross")

df_wanted = pd.merge(df_aux, uses, how="left", on=["person_id", "loop_id"])
```

That give me all possibilities from loop_merge combined with all persons loop_id. So I will have multiples rows for loops done by person, if they have done multiple times, and the rows that doesnt match will have columns NaN which means that person didnt do that loop.

I hope that this help someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas 1.2.0., you can [cross merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html). Then using a boolean mask, assign NaN values to "another_column" on rows loop_ids don't match:

```
merged_df = uses.merge(loop_merge, how='cross', suffixes=('_',''))
merged_df.loc[merged_df['loop_id_']!=merged_df['loop_id'], 'another_column'] = np.nan
merged_df.drop('loop_id_', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   person_id another_column  loop_id description
0          1          Hello        1         foo
1          1            NaN        2         bar
2          2             Hi        1         foo
3          2            NaN        2         bar
4          3          Hello        1         foo
5          3            NaN        2         bar
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that if there is a dataframe like: 
uses = {'person_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1], 'loop_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1], 'another_column': ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello']}

loop_merge = pd.DataFrame({'loop_id': [1, 2, 3], 'description': ['foo', 'bar', 'zoo']})

It will increase my dataframe exponentially. I just want to add extra rows where it didnt match. I dont wnat to do an cartesian product with every row.

Comment: @JafetHenriqueGuerraFagundes for that pairs of dfs, what is the expected outcome if not a Cartesian product?

Comment: I have found the solution by mysql and posted it. Hope that help someone in the future